# transform one long row in data-frame to individual records

Tags: r, dataframe, transform

I have a variable list of people I get as one long row in a data frame and I am interested to reorganize these record into a more meaningful format.

My raw data looks like this,

```
df <- data.frame(name1 = "John Doe", email1 = "John@Doe.com", phone1 = "(444) 444-4444", name2 = "Jane Doe", email2 = "Jane@Doe.com", phone2 = "(444) 444-4445", name3 = "John Smith", email3 = "John@Smith.com", phone3 = "(444) 444-4446", name4 = NA, email4 = "Jane@Smith.com", phone4 = NA, name5 = NA, email5 = NA, phone5 = NA)
df
#     name1       email1         phone1    name2       email2         phone2
# 1 John Doe John@Doe.com (444) 444-4444 Jane Doe Jane@Doe.com (444) 444-4445
#       name3         email3         phone3 name4         email4 phone4 name5
# 1 John Smith John@Smith.com (444) 444-4446    NA Jane@Smith.com     NA    NA
#  email5 phone5
# 1     NA     NA
```

and I am trying to bend it into a format like this,

```
df_transform <- structure(list(name = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, NA, NA), .Label = c("Jane Doe", 
"John Doe", "John Smith"), class = "factor"), email = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("Jane@Doe.com", "Jane@Smith.com", 
"John@Doe.com", "John@Smith.com"), class = "factor"), phone = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, NA, NA), .Label = c("(444) 444-4444", "(444) 444-4445", 
"(444) 444-4446"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("name", "email", 
"phone"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
 df_transform
#         name          email          phone
# 1   John Doe   John@Doe.com (444) 444-4444
# 2   Jane Doe   Jane@Doe.com (444) 444-4445
# 3 John Smith John@Smith.com (444) 444-4446
# 4       <NA> Jane@Smith.com           <NA>
# 5       <NA>           <NA>           <NA>
```

It should be added that it's not always five record, it could be any number between 1 and 99. I tried with `reshape2`'s `melt` and `t()1 but it got way to complicated. I imagine there is some know method that I simply do not know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **reshape()** First we strip off the digits from the column names giving the reduced column names, `names0`.  Then we split the columns into groups producing `g` (which has three components corresponding to the `email`, `name` and `phone` column groups).  Then use `reshape` (from the base of R) to perform the wide to long transformation and select from the resulting long data frame the desired columns in order to exclude the columns that are added automatically by `reshape`.  That selection vector, `unique(names0)`, is such that it reorders the resulting columns in the desired way.

```
names0 <- sub("\\d+$", "", names(df))
g <- split(names(df), names0)
reshape(df, dir = "long", varying = g, v.names = names(g))[unique(names0)]
```

and the last line gives this:

```
          name          email          phone
1.1   John Doe   John@Doe.com (444) 444-4444
1.2   Jane Doe   Jane@Doe.com (444) 444-4445
1.3 John Smith John@Smith.com (444) 444-4446
1.4       <NA> Jane@Smith.com           <NA>
1.5       <NA>           <NA>           <NA>
```

2) **reshape2 package** Here is a solution using reshape2.  We add a `rowname` column to `df` and `melt` it to long form. Then we split the `variable` column into the name portion (`name`, `email`, `phone`) and the numeric suffix portion which we call `id`.  Finally we convert it back to wide form using `dcast` and select out the appropriate columns as we did before.

```
library(reshape2)

m <- melt(data.frame(rowname = 1:nrow(df), df), id = 1)
mt <- transform(m, 
   variable = sub("\\d+$", "", variable), 
   id = sub("^\\D+", "", variable)
)
dcast(mt, rowname + id ~ variable)[, unique(mt$variable)]
```

where the last line gives this:

```
        name          email          phone
1   John Doe   John@Doe.com (444) 444-4444
2   Jane Doe   Jane@Doe.com (444) 444-4445
3 John Smith John@Smith.com (444) 444-4446
4       <NA> Jane@Smith.com           <NA>
5       <NA>           <NA>           <NA>
```

3) **Simple matrix reshaping** .  Remove the numeric suffixes from the column names and set `cn` to the unique remaining names. (`cn` stands for column names).  Then we merely reshape the `df` row into an n x length(cn) matrix adding the column names.

```
cn <- unique(sub("\\d+$", "", names(df)))
matrix(as.matrix(df), nc = length(cn), byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, cn))

     name         email            phone           
[1,] "John Doe"   "John@Doe.com"   "(444) 444-4444"
[2,] "Jane Doe"   "Jane@Doe.com"   "(444) 444-4445"
[3,] "John Smith" "John@Smith.com" "(444) 444-4446"
[4,] NA           "Jane@Smith.com" NA              
[5,] NA           NA               NA
```

4) **tapply** This problem can also be solved with a simple `tapply`.  As before `names0` is the column names without the numeric suffixes.  `names.suffix` is just the suffixes.  Now use `tapply` :

```
names0 <- sub("\\d+$", "", names(df))
names.suffix <- sub("^\\D+", "", names(df))
tapply(as.matrix(df), list(names.suffix, names0), c)[, unique(names0)]
```

The last line gives:

```
  name         email            phone           
1 "John Doe"   "John@Doe.com"   "(444) 444-4444"
2 "Jane Doe"   "Jane@Doe.com"   "(444) 444-4445"
3 "John Smith" "John@Smith.com" "(444) 444-4446"
4 NA           "Jane@Smith.com" NA              
5 NA           NA               NA
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your answer and that you are only using base-R

Comment: The varying argument of `reshape()` seems more geared to the problem than the corresponding reshape2 solution but the matrix reshaping and `tapply` solutions which have also been added may be the simplest of them all.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track, try this:

```
library(reshape2)

# melt it down
df.melted = melt(t(df))
# get rid of the numbers at the end
df.melted$Var1 = sub('[0-9]+$', '', df.melted$Var1)

# cast it back
dcast(df.melted, (seq_len(nrow(df.melted)) - 1) %/% 3 ~ Var1)[,-1]
#           email       name          phone
#1   John@Doe.com   John Doe (444) 444-4444
#2   Jane@Doe.com   Jane Doe (444) 444-4445
#3 John@Smith.com John Smith (444) 444-4446
#4 Jane@Smith.com       <NA>           <NA>
#5           <NA>       <NA>           <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that you are using the tool I mentioned.